# Pulling AD User objects with directreports property

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and I am have been searching for a script that can pull AD User objects that are (Enabled) and have direct-reports.  I don't need to know their Direct-Reports I just need a list of Users that have Direct reports.  I have been playing around with ideas but I am too new to this to come up with anything useful.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't too bad if you get the syntax of PowerShell.  The first thing you do is tell PowerShell to import Active Directory functionality:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

Then just tell it to get any AD user's properties called `displayname`, `directReports` and `enabled`, take that information and tell it for any of these that have anything in `directReports` and where the AD account is currently enabled, report back the `samAccountName` and the `displayName`.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties DisplayName, directReports, enabled | Where{($_.directReports -Like "*") -And ($_.enabled -eq $True)} | select samAccountName, displayName
```

You can select any property of an AD account to retrieve; it's essentially any attribute in AD and a little bit more.  The `directReports` and `enabled` start with a `$_.` in the `Where` statement to let PowerShell know they're the values from before the pipe.  A pipe is the `|` symbol which basically lets you take data from the left side of it and do another activity with it on the right side.

You might want to pipe that out to an `Export-Csv myfile.csv -noTypeInformation` so you get it as a file instead of just an on-screen readout.

Here's a great site for learning the commands in PowerShell:  http://ss64.com/ps/.

If this response resolves your issue, please check the box as the accepted answer so the question falls off the unanswered list.